# TypeError: post() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to edit data from a table in a template:

[image: Table]

I click on "Edit" button but I get this error: `post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'folio'`

[image: Error]

Here is my **urls.py**

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from django.urls import path, include, re_path
 from . import views
 from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

 app_name = 'oficios'

 urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.lista_oficios, name="list"),
    path('crear/', views.crear_oficio, name="crear"),
    path('dependencia/', views.agregar_dependencia, name="dependencia"),
    path('editar/', views.EditarOficio.as_view(), name="editar"),
    path('editar/<str:folio>/', views.EditarOficio.as_view(), name="editar"),
]
```

My **views.py**:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class EditarOficio(CreateView):

    model = Oficio
    fields = ['folio', 'usuario', 'asunto',
              'estatus', 'documento', 'dependencia', 'turnado']

    def get(self, request, folio):
        oficio = Oficio.objects.get(id=folio)
        form = forms.CreateOficio(instance=oficio)
        context = {
            "form": form,
            "title": "Editar oficio " + oficio.folio
        }
        return render(request, "editar_oficio.html", context)

    def post(self, request, folio):
        oficio = Oficio.objects.get(id=folio)
        print(oficio)
        form = forms.CreateOficio(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=oficio)
        context = {
            "form": form,
            "title": "Editar oficio " + oficio.folio
        }
        if(form.is_valid()):
            oficio = form.save(commit=False)
            oficio.save()
            return redirect('oficios:list')
        return render(request, "editar_oficio.html", context)
```

My **models.py**:

```
class Oficio(models.Model):

    class Estatus(models.TextChoices):
        NUEVO = 'NU', _('Nuevo')
        NO_REVISADO = 'NR', _('No Revisado')
        LEIDO = 'L', _('Leido')
        SEGUIMIENTO = 'S', _('Seguimiento')
        COMPLETADO = 'C', _('Completado')

    folio = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True, max_length=10, unique=True, null=False)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    asunto = models.TextField(null=False)
    estatus = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=Estatus.choices, default=Estatus.NUEVO)
    documento = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf')
    dependencia = models.ForeignKey(
        'Dependencia', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dependencia_origen')
    turnado = models.ForeignKey(
        'Dependencia', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dependencia_destino')
```

My **template**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>EDITAR OFICIO</h1>

     <form class="" action="{% url 'oficios:editar' oficio.folio %}" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Editar</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I tried changing the last `post` parameter with `slug=None` but then I have no "id" for the object I am trying to update. I don't know what I am doing wrong, can someone advice me? Please

Comment: What is the URL in the `action` param of the form when the page is rendered?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Where is the `action` function?

Comment: What does this section look like when you view the page source; `action="{% url 'oficios:editar' oficio.folio %}"`

Comment: It redirects me to `http://localhost:8000/oficios/editar/` but shows a Django error page like in the image above with `post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'folio'`

I read that `oficios.folio` need to be there so the template passes through the "id" to the views.py file :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by having two URLs of the same name I think you'll get conflict within the system as to what URL is being used and which URL the user is being sent to.

Django checks URLs in order so the first that matches is the URL that's hit.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('editar/', views.EditarOficio.as_view(), name="editar"),
    path('editar/<str:folio>/', views.EditarOficio.as_view(), name="editar"),
]
```

In your class `EditarOficio`, both `get` and `post` requests require a `folio` argument to be present, which then means that the first URL which doesn't pass that parameter, isn't valid.

I'd start by having two different names here so that you can target each URL as you need to. You've suggested that this still doesn't resolve things so at this point I'd also change the path itself to something besides `editar`, if only for debugging this problem. Because you've said this issue still exists after defining different names, that then sounds like `oficio.folio` doesn't have a value or something unexpected is going on.

You should debug in the template by trying to display data like `{{ oficio.folio }}` etc to confirm the data is available.

Based on your template, it looks as though you aren't passing the necessary data in the context in order to form the correct URL to post your form to.

Your template attempts to do `oficio.folio` in the formation of the URL, but `oficio` is not available in the context.

Try to make some changes similar to this;

```py
    @method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
    class EditarOficio(CreateView):
    
        model = Oficio
        fields = ['folio', 'usuario', 'asunto',
                  'estatus', 'documento', 'dependencia', 'turnado']
    
        def get(self, request, folio):
            oficio = Oficio.objects.get(id=folio)
            form = forms.CreateOficio(instance=oficio)
            context = {
                "form": form,
                "oficio": oficio,
                "title": "Editar oficio " + oficio.folio
            }
            return render(request, "editar_oficio.html", context)
    
        def post(self, request, folio):
            oficio = Oficio.objects.get(id=folio)
            print(oficio)
            form = forms.CreateOficio(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=oficio)
            context = {
                "form": form,
                "oficio": oficio,
                "title": "Editar oficio " + oficio.folio
            }
            if(form.is_valid()):
                oficio = form.save(commit=False)
                oficio.save()
                return redirect('oficios:list')
            return render(request, "editar_oficio.html", context)
```

Alternatively, `oficio` is the instance of the form, so you could probably do the following while leaving your view as it is:

`{% url 'oficios:editar' form.instance.folio %}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am still getting `TypeError at /oficios/editar/
post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'folio'` with both solutions provided. I don't know why if I get `folio` from `oficio = Oficio.objects.get(id=folio)`, I even print this variable and gets me exactly what I want, the pk of that model I'm trying to update

Comment: @Danny I think the issue may have something to do with the fact you've got 2 URLs with the same name. I'd recommend having 2 names for those 2 URLs.

Comment: I've done that, redirected every time the "EDIT" button is activated to `path('editar/<str:folio>/', views.EditarOficio.as_view(), name="editar"),` but still got the post() missing 1 required positional argument. I tried with `slug=None` in the post def and I was able to get to the form to update every field on it but when accepting the changes I was redirected to the same page with no save in the DB

Comment: @Danny I've added some further explanation about URLs, but its sounding like this needs debugging to find out what's actually going on.

Comment: Hey @markwalker_ I decided to make mi views with methods instead of classes, in that proccess I realized that in the `action` parameter in the "EDIT" button was taking me to another url, also I didn't pass the key of the object in that tamplate (the first image). So problem solved, thank you to take the time to review my question, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Danny I was focusing on the `post` from your form & in your view, but just seen `folio` is a required arg for the `get` request as well which means your first URL which didn't include that param would never have worked because it didn't have the param for get or post requests.